# AWS network interface (eni) flow logs enrichment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

My solution uses different sets of ECS Fargate containers to accomplish the tasks. Each container belongs to a single client (authenticated through Cognito if that matters). I want to be able to capture (primarily outgoing) flow logs for security purposes. As I have my orchestrator who is bringing up and shutting down the containers, I have a neat way of attaching flow logs to each eni separately (as opposed to the whole VPC or subnet), thus knowing the owner of the flow log. My problem is how to add this information to the flow log, preferably clean and neat. I'd also like this to be in S3 so I can send it to Glacier.

One idea I was investigating is the ability to tag the flow logs, but it seems only the flow logs themselves are tagged, not their corresponding S3 files. Can anyone confirm this? I need to do some more tests here.

The other method was partially successful. I was using an S3 bucket ARN with a subfolder, where the subfolder kept the extra data. The problem here is that this method has off-information levels. It should be account—date—time—user, and not user—account—date—time. Does anyone know if there is any good way to flip the folder structure arbitrarily with flow log settings so that I don't have to employ a lambda?

Thanks for any ideas!